# div is hovering other div

Tags: html, css

Problem:
[Div newline is hovering div gallery-preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5qP6F.png)

I'm trying to make gallerys preview and a have made div with table. **gallery-preview** div is inline, to be in one line with others. How to make **newline** div be in bottom of **gallery-preview** divs line? And why **newline** is hovering **gallery-preview**?

My HTML:

```
        <div class="content">
        <h1 class="title">New Photosets</h1>
        <div class="gallery-preview">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <img src="image.png" class="gallery-preview-big-image" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <img src="image.png" class="gallery-preview-small-image" />
                        <img src="image.png" class="gallery-preview-small-image" />
                        <img src="image.png" class="gallery-preview-small-image" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div class="newline"></div>
```

My CSS:

```
.newline{
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
/* --------------- */
/* Content Gallery */

.gallery-preview{
    padding-right: 1%;
    display: inline;
    float: left;
}
.gallery-preview-big-image{
    width: 166px;
    height: 166px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}
.gallery-preview-small-image{
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    padding-right: 4px;
    display: inline;
}

/* --------- */
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is probably because of the `float` property.

Try to add `clear:both;` into your `.newline` style.

Answer (score 0):

[If this is what you want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zTgCp.png)

Than you just have to remove `float:left` from .gallery-preview

Comment: http://image.prntscr.com/image/889f8c9312fb40caaeedb6484109a269.png

They aren't inline anymore.